# What is the recommended format to import tables from Excel to arc map with more than 65 536 rows? CSV?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv

What is the recommended format to import tables from Excel to Arc map with more than 65 536 rows? CSV?Txt?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you on? Excel 2007+ with .xlsx format supports more rows, no problem to read more than 65536 rows.

Comment: 10.2.1  but I can´t import .xlsx

Comment: Double-click the .xlsx file in Catalog window and drag a sheet into ArcMap.

Comment: In the catalog window I can´t see .xlsx files only .xls

Comment: Which means you are working with .xls file. Let's try this. Do you have access to Office 2007+? If so, just resave your Excel file as .xlxs and open this one in ArcMap instead.

Comment: I have a .xls file and a .xlsx  in the same folder, strangely I can only see the .xls...

Comment: Close Excel if you have this .xlsx file open there and if no help - restart ArcMap. Are you able to open the .xlsx file in Excel (make sure it is not corrupted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always get the failed to load table error when dragging or trying to access xlxs sheet in ArcGIS.  One option that works for xlsx is the [Excel to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000055000000) tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you import to a file geodatabase table you will be able to handle a lot more rows than that.

It sounds like you are currently trying to use dBase or MS Access.